# Change calendar location viewer

Tags: google-calendar

When I put in a location for an event in the Google Calendar on my Nexus 4, and then select it later it opens up in Google Earth which I do not want to happen.

How can I change it to open in Google Maps, so I can use the location for directions?

I have looked under `Settings > calendar` but there was nothing under the default open header.

Am I looking in right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm prompted to select what I want to use to open the link, so it looks like you've set a default action for that Intent.

You'll need to go to `Settings > Apps > (downloaded or all) > Earth > Clear defaults`. Next time you click a location in the calendar it should prompt you for what you want to use to open it.

Unfortunately, this resets all the defaults for Google Earth.

Comment: Thanks, i went and checked `system > apps > calender`. Didnt think of checking earth thanks for the help

Comment: It's always the app reacting to your request you need to check whether it's set as default. Think of it as an "on duty" badge: the one wearing it does the job. So if you want someone else doing it, you know where to pick the badge :)